# What does backend_xmin and backend_xid represent in pg_stat_activity?

Tags: postgresql

Postgresql exposes the view `pg_stat_activity`. As per the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/monitoring-stats.html),

`backend_xid` means Top-level transaction identifier of this backend, if any.

`backend_xmin` means The current backend's xmin horizon.

Let us take an example:

```
BEGIN;
# INSERT Statement1
# INSERT Statement2
COMMIT;
```

`backend_xid` represents the transaction identifier allotted to the full transaction while if `pg_stat_activity` shows the statement2 in its row, then `backend_xmin` corresponds to the `xmin` for statement2.

Is the understanding correct?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These two values represent the *snapshot* of the transaction.

Whenever a query starts (or, with `REPEATABLE READ` isolation level, when the first query in the transaction starts), PostgreSQL takes a snapshot of the database. That means that the query (or the transaction) sees a certain state of the database, no matter what concurrent data modifications happened in the meantime.

Such a snapshot consists of the oldest transaction ID of any active transaction at the time (`xmin`), the transaction ID of the newest active transaction (`xmax`) and a list of the transaction IDs of all currently active transactions. With the aid of these numbers, PostgreSQL can determine if a tuple (a row version) is *visible* or not.

`backend_xmin` is relevant because (together with other values) the oldest one determines the *`xmin` horizon*, which is the cut-off point for dead tuples that autovacuum can safely remove.