# PSQL: VACUUM ANALYZE is showing incorrect oldest xmin

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora, vacuum

When I run vacuum verbose on a table, the result is showing an oldest `xmin` value of 9696975, as shown below:

> ```
> table_xxx: found 0 removable, 41472710 nonremovable row versions in 482550 out of 482550 pages
> DETAIL:  41331110 dead row versions cannot be removed yet, oldest xmin: 9696975
> There were 0 unused item identifiers.
> ```

But when I check in `pg_stat_activity`, there are no entries with the `backend_xmin` value that matches this oldest `xmin` value.
Below is the response I get when I run the query:

```
SELECT backend_xmin
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE backend_xmin IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY age(backend_xmin) DESC;
```

**Response:**

```
backend_xmin
------------
10134695
10134696
10134696
10134696
10134696
```

The issue I am facing is that the vacuum is not removing any dead tuples from the table.
I tried methods mentioned in: [this post](https://minervadb.com/index.php/2020/04/29/when-postgresql-vacuum-wont-remove-dead-rows-from-a-table/). But it didn't help.

**edit:**
The PostgreSQL version is 13.6 running in Aurora cluster.

Comment: I would query [pg_locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-locks.html).

Comment: I tried running the query:
 "SELECT query,backend_xmin, state,locktype,mode
FROM pg_locks
JOIN pg_stat_activity
  USING (pid)
WHERE relation::regclass = 'table_xxx'::regclass
  AND granted IS TRUE
  AND backend_xmin IS NOT NULL;"
But it is returning empty result

Comment: Try a plain `select * from pg_locks`  to see if there are any locks.

Comment: What version of Postgres is this? Add as update to question. I ask as the latest releases have this: "Allow parallel vacuuming and concurrent index building to be ignored while computing oldest xmin. Non-parallelized instances of these operations were already ignored, but the logic did not work for parallelized cases. Holding back the xmin horizon has undesirable effects such as delaying vacuum cleanup."

Comment: The version is 13.6, running in Aurora cluster (Also added as update to the question). Does rebooting the db instance reset the xmin value?

Comment: 1) 13.6 has the fix assuming AWS just passes that along in its version. 2) Are there any locks? 3) I am not aware that a reboot changes the xmin value. What needs to be kept in mind is from here [Postgres Aurora](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/postgresql-features/): "The PostgreSQL-compatible edition of Aurora delivers up to 3X the throughput of standard PostgreSQL running on the same hardware, ..." . Not exactly sure what AWS does to Postgres when modifying it for Aurora.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `backend_xmin`, also check `backend_xid` from `pg_stat_activity`. A transaction that has a transaction ID can also block `VACUUM` progress.

Apart from old transactions, there are some other things that can hold the “xmin horizon” back:

- stale replication slots (see `pg_replication_slots`)
- abandoned prepared transactions (see `pg_prepared_xacts`)
- a standby server with `hot_standby_feedback = on` that is running a long query (look at `backend_xmin` in `pg_stat_replication`)

For more details, see [my article on the topic](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/reasons-why-vacuum-wont-remove-dead-rows/).

Comment: we faced a similar problem wrt vacuum not able to function properly and the problem was with a stale replication slot.

Answer (score 0):

A row is only completely dead when no live transaction can see it anymore. I.e. no transaction that has been started before the row was updated / deleted is still running. That does not necessarily involve any locks at all. The mere existence of a long-running transaction can block `VACUUM` from cleaning up.

So the system view to consult is [`pg_stat_activity`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW). Look for zombi-transactions that you can kill. Then `VACUUM` can proceed.

Old prepared transactions can also block for the same reason. You can check [`pg_prepared_xacts`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-prepared-xacts.html) for those.

Of course, `VACUUM` only runs on the primary server, not on replicas (standby) instances - in case [streaming replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/warm-standby.html#STREAMING-REPLICATION) has been set up.

Related:

- [Long running function locking the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53088738/long-running-function-locking-the-database/53089825#53089825)
- [What are the consequences of not ending a database transaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33815267/what-are-the-consequences-of-not-ending-a-database-transaction/33815610#33815610)
- [What does backend_xmin and backend_xid represent in pg_stat_activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63837676/what-does-backend-xmin-and-backend-xid-represent-in-pg-stat-activity/63840171#63840171)
- [Do postgres autovacuum properties persist for DB replications?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/233151/3684)

Comment: I did look at the pg_stat_activity, to look for any idle transactions that were running for long. But we could not see any. However we have tried rebooting the db instance, and after that the vacuum has successfully removed the dead tuples.

Comment: @thomas: A reboot (restart) is a brute-force catch-all. But you'll never know what actually blocked now ....

Comment: yes, that is what I am still worried about. Since I am still unsure of the actual cause, I think the same issue may occur in future: may be with more damage. But as this issue was causing downtime in our live applications, I went with the restart approach. Though I will retry to reproduce the same issue in our staging/dev servers to find out the root cause.

Comment: @thomas next time, you want to look at backend_xid, not backend_xmin from pg_stat_activity.  The first one might tell you who is causing the problem, while the second is just who is a victim of the problem.